# Lowercase query parameters in URL using iOS universal links

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, ios-universal-links, nsuseractivity

I was just about to link an app to a domain using universal links (or also refered to as associated domains; [available since iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)). So far everything worked out and while testing with Safari I was able to open my app correctly, also parse path and query parameters of any URL.

But when I opened an URL that worked before with Safari from inside iMessage or Mail it failed.
I found out that when opening an app that way each query parameter gets reformatted to lowercase characters, which is invalid towards my data handling.
For example

```
https://www.example.com/path?paramNameOne=ValueOne&paramNameTwo=ValueTwo
```

is altered to

```
https://www.example.com/path?paramnameone=valueone&paramnametwo=valuetwo
```

So question is if there is a detail with this technology that I'm not aware of or - in case of a known bug - a propper strategy to cope with this issue.

Comment: Hard to say if you don't explain or show your actual data handling.

Comment: @ff10 That should be irrelevant. When you transport something like "...?productId=AZ_42" and the app recieved "...?productid=az_42" any handling should be screwed in cases were e.g. searching for elements is case sensitive. Also comparing the parameter name would fail in normal isEqualToString: checks. Of course I could try to revert that somewhere my data has been changed, but I would prefere to recieve exactly what an URL looked like originally.

Comment: That is if your search has to be case sensitive. But it appears that this point is crucial to you.

Comment: @ff10 Still should be irrelevant to the question/problem. You tap onto any URL in iMessage, Mail, whatever that contains case sensitive data and your app just recieves an NSUserActivity that has a lowercase URL. However I deal with data... I recieve wrong data in the first place. And that's what I try to fix and solve.

Answer (score -1):

Universal linking does not accept font formatting. Remove styling from your link and check